# PHP: using empty() for empty string?

Tags: php

I recently discovered this interesting [article](http://kunststube.net/isset/) by [Deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze).
But I'm a bit confused by one of its advises:

> never use empty or isset for variables that should exist

Using `empty()` is not good choice to test if `$foo = '';` is empty?

Comment: Is there any situation in which `$foo` itself **may not exist**? Unless that's a legitimate possibility you want to account for, don't use `empty`; `== false` would do the same thing without disabling error reporting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use `empty` (or `isset`) if you expect `$foo` to exist. That means, if according to your program logic, `$foo` should exist at this point:

```
if ($foo === '')
```

Then **do not** do any of these:

```
if (isset($foo))
if (empty($foo))
```

These two language constructs *suppress error reporting for undefined variables*. That's their only job. That means, if you use `isset` or `empty` gratuitously, PHP won't tell you about problems in your code. For example:

```
$foo = $bar;
if (empty($føø)) ...
```

Hmm, why is this *always* `true`, even when `$bar` contains the expected value? Because you mistyped the variable name and you're checking the value of an undefined variable. Write it like this instead to let PHP help you:

```
if (!$føø) ...
```

> Notice: undefined variable føø on line ...

The condition itself is the same, `== false` (`!`) and `empty` produce the same outcome for the same values.

How exactly to check for an empty string depends on what values you do or don't accept. Perhaps `$foo === ''` or `strlen($foo) == 0` is the check you're looking for to ensure you have a string with *something* in it.

Answer (score 7):

What he means is if you want to check if the string is empty then empty won't do that. Empty can mean false, 0, null. Anything 'falsy'.

E.g. these are all true:

```
<?php

$string = null;
if (empty($string)) {
    echo "This is true";
}

$string = '';
if (empty($string)) {
    echo "This is true";
}

$string = 0;
if (empty($string)) {
    echo "This is true";
}
```

If you want to check if the string is an empty string you should do this check for '':

```
<?php 

$string = '';
if (isset($string) && $string === '') {
    echo "This is true";
}

$string = null;
if (isset($string) && $string === '') {
    echo "This is false";
}
```

Comment: That's not actually what he means. He means that unless you're unsure whether **the variable itself** may or may not be set, don't use `empty` or `isset`. In all your examples the variable `$string` is guaranteed to exist when you're trying to use it, so the `isset` check (and by extension `empty`) is completely superfluous. How exactly to check "how empty" your string is is a different topic. `strlen` would be the best test for that.

Comment: @deceze answer is much better

Comment: Not only superfluous but actually harmful. Because isset and empty are just little brothers of @.

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `empty()` can be used in many cases.

It works for checking:

- if a string is `blank`
- if a variable is `undefined` or `null`

And of course `empty()` is best for your case too.

Comment: Also if a blank array - plus all those other "falsey" alternatives (`(int) 0`, etc).

Comment: `empty` does exactly the same thing as `== false`, except it doesn't throw any errors if the whole variable you're testing doesn't exist (`empty($undefined)` → no errors, `$undefined == false` → `Notice: undefined variable`).

Comment: On the contrary, anything but "best"

Answer (score -1):

Check String is empty or Not

```php
<?php
     $test='';
     if(empty($test)){
          echo'It is empty';
     } else{
          echo'Its not empty';
     }
?>
```

Comment: The accepted answer explicitly explains why you shouldn't

Answer (score -2):

Try using this php if function:
$retVal = (condition) ? a : b ;

where condition: **$value == null**

a: **is the value to display if $value is null**

b: **is the actual value to display or any other value to be displayed when $value is not null**

In case of further guidance, kindly comment