# Don't Display Column/Row if value is empty/null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying SQL data on a webpage that is used on different tables that display a different number of columns. For the tables that have null values, I do not want those to show on the HTML table. How do I create it so that they do not display?

```
<?php
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM lists WHERE id = $listid";

    $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $list_id = $row['list_id'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        $col1_name = $row['col1_name'];
        $col2_name = $row['col2_name'];
        $col3_name = $row['col3_name'];
        $col4_name = $row['col4_name'];
        $col5_name = $row['col5_name'];
        $col6_name = $row['col6_name'];
        $col7_name = $row['col7_name'];
        $col8_name = $row['col8_name'];
        $col9_name = $row['col9_name'];
        $col10_name = $row['col10_name'];
        $col11_name = $row['col11_name'];
        $col12_name = $row['col12_name'];
        $col13_name = $row['col13_name'];
        $col14_name = $row['col14_name'];
        $col15_name = $row['col15_name'];
     } 

    // $id = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM list_rows WHERE list_id = $listid";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows) {

    echo "<table class='w3-table-all' id='datatable'>
    <thead>
        <tr class='w3-indigo'>";
            if (!empty($row['col1_name'])){echo "<th>".$col1_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col2_name'])){echo "<th>".$col2_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col3_name'])){echo "<th>".$col3_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col4_name'])){echo "<th>".$col4_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col5_name'])){echo "<th>".$col5_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col6_name'])){echo "<th>".$col6_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col7_name'])){echo "<th>".$col7_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col8_name'])){echo "<th>".$col8_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col9_name'])){echo "<th>".$col9_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col10_name'])){echo "<th>".$col10_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col11_name'])){echo "<th>".$col11_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col12_name'])){echo "<th>".$col12_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col13_name'])){echo "<th>".$col13_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col14_name'])){echo "<th>".$col14_name."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row['col15_name'])){echo "<th>".$col15_name."</th>";}


        echo "</tr>
    </thead>";

    // output data of each row
    echo "<tbody>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
        echo "
        <tr class='w3-hover-pale-blue'>";
            if (!empty($row["col1_value"])){echo "<th>".$col1_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col2_value"])){echo "<th>".$col2_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col3_value"])){echo "<th>".$col3_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col4_value"])){echo "<th>".$col4_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col5_value"])){echo "<th>".$col5_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col6_value"])){echo "<th>".$col6_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col7_value"])){echo "<th>".$col7_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col8_value"])){echo "<th>".$col8_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col9_value"])){echo "<th>".$col9_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col10_value"])){echo "<th>".$col10_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col11_value"])){echo "<th>".$col11_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col12_value"])){echo "<th>".$col12_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col13_value"])){echo "<th>".$col13_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col14_value"])){echo "<th>".$col14_value."</th>";}
            if (!empty($row["col15_value"])){echo "<th>".$col15_value."</th>";}
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo "</div>";

//$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I've also tried:

```
if (!is_null($row['col1_name'])){echo "<th>".$col1_name."</th>";}
```

and is_null, as well as:

```
if ($row['col1_name'] != null){echo "<th>".$col1_name."</th>";}
```

And none of these variations have worked. It either displays an empty table or displays nothing at all.

[image]
It displays empty columns. I do not want those columns to appear if they are empty.

```
col1_name | col2_name | col3_name | col4_name | col5_name | col6_name | col7_name | col8_name | col9_name | col10_name | col11_name | col12_name | col13_name | col14_name | col15_name |
Item------| One_Day---| Three_Days | Ten_Days | Totals----| Notes-----| Facility--| Department| NULL------| NULL-------| NULL-------| NULL-------| NULL-------| NULL-------| NULL-------|
```

database data

Comment: Can you demonstrate the desired result on some sample data?

Comment: Also, why are you comparing to the `$row["col15_value"]` database result but printing the newly defined variable `$col15_value`? Shouldn't really matter, but just curious if those variables were used other places.

Comment: @PM77-1 I amended my original post.

Comment: `NULL` values != "empty", you need to remember that. If you want to check either/or, then you need to use the `OR` logical operator.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: try using this: $retVal = (condition) ? a : b ;

Answer (score 0):

According to this StackOverflow post ([PHP: using empty() for empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784959/php-using-empty-for-empty-string)), you shouldn't use `empty` to determine string length since the variable exists itself. `empty` is best used for arrays given some of the complicated cases that occur.

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for `empty`, the following cases would evaluate to `empty` returning TRUE.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Therefore, I would compare against an empty string:

```
if ($row['col1_name'] == ''){echo "<th>".$col1_name."</th>";}
```

Comment: that embedded link you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784959/php-using-empty-for-empty-string I feel is a duplicate for this question.

Comment: I would agree, assuming that the correction of the use of `empty` solved his/her issue.

Comment: @KeithChason Using `if ($row['col1_name'] == ''){echo "<th>".$col1_name."</th>";}` didn't change anything. It still displayed the empty column headers.

Comment: @xxdash, were all of the related (below) `<td>` cells blank too?

Comment: @KeithChason that is correct. There is no `<td>` data where the `<th>` is empty.